# Read Excel Cell text with Superscript

Tags: c#, excel

[image]

I want to read Excel cell content in .NET. My cell content looks like "Seller(1)". I tried the below code but it returns empty string.

```
Range oRng = (Range)Worksheet.Cells[i, j];
string str = oRng.Text.ToString();
```

I tried all the properties but none of them is returning the actual text.